# MVC call a partial view without calling model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

On my home page (which uses the HomePage model) I need to call a partial which uses a different model.

I keep getting the error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Site.Models.HomeModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Site.Models.DifferentModel'

How I'm trying to call my partial view.

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_partialItem.cshtml")
```

is there a way of doing this without changing the controller?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try 
`@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_partialItem.cshtml",new DifferentModel(){})`

Comment: This should really be a comment if it's a suggestion